# Spread props in react native props throws wrong error in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have an react native(expo) project which is using typescript.

However, when I try to pass spreaded props to a component, it throws an error.

For example:

```js
const props: TextInputProps = {
  value: "foo",
  onChangeText: (text: string) => { /*...*/ }
};

// (code ommited)

<TextInput {...props} />   // Type ...TextInputProps is not assignable to type React.ReactNode | undefined
```

I don't see why the prop of the component is claimed as `React.ReactNode`.

It seems it might be a problem with my typescript config, so I include my settings.

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

where `expo/tsconfig.base` is, FYI:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

I have these packages on my `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  // ...
  "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
  "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the problem was my `node` version. I was using `v12.22.1` but when I upgraded to `v18.17.0`, the error was gone.